# get radio button values in angular5

Tags: angular

I have this value `Rating=7`  in my database and I am getting this value and storing on editUserDetails={}. Now I am displaying 5 to 9 radio buttons in the browser and I want to select the radio button according to the database value. I mean I want to select the radio with `value = 7`. I wrote this code but it is not working. What's the issue and what I need to put. Can someone please help?

> my Html

```
<div class="col-md-6" *ngFor="let Rating of rates">
            <input type="radio" name="Rating" [value]="Rating" [checked]="radioChange(Rating)"> 
            {{Rating.rating}}
          </div>
```

> my Ts

```
rates:any=[
    {rating:"5"},
    {rating:"6"},
    {rating:"7"},
    {rating:"8"},
    {rating:"9"},
    ]

    radioChange(Rating){
     var match=false;
     if(this.editUserDetails.Rating===Rating){
       match=true;
     }else{}
     this.temp = 0;
     return match;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

strong text

```js
//.ts file 

data:string;//gloabal declaration 

 rates:any=[
    {rating:"5"},
    {rating:"6"},
    {rating:"7"},
    {rating:"8"},
    {rating:"9"},
    ]
    
    
    ngOnInit(){
    
    this.data="7";//your formatt
    }
```

```html
 <div class="col-md-6" *ngFor="let Rating of rates">
 <input type="radio" name="radiodata" [value]="Rating.rating" [(ngModel)]="data"> {{Rating.rating}}
                      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to use the built-in two-way binding. My radio buttons look more like this:

```
<div class="col-md-6" *ngFor="let Rating of rates">
            <input type="radio" 
                   name="Rating"
                   [value]="Rating"
                   [(ngModel)]="selectedRating"> 
            {{Rating.rating}}
</div>
```

And the component then looks like this:

```
selectedRating:any;

rates:any=[
    {rating:"5"},
    {rating:"6"},
    {rating:"7"},
    {rating:"8"},
    {rating:"9"},
    ]
```

Then in the `ngOnit()`, after you've retrieved your data:

```
   console.log(this.editUserDetails.Rating);
   this.selectedRating = this.rates.find(item => 
       item.rating === this.editUserDetails.Rating.rating);
```

This complexity is due to the fact you are binding the objects instead of the numbers. This code finds the *exact* matching object in the array.

If the values are indeed numbers, it may be easier to bind the numbers instead.

```
<div class="col-md-6" *ngFor="let Rating of rates">
            <input type="radio" 
                   name="Rating"
                   [value]="Rating.rating"
                   [(ngModel)]="selectedRating"> 
            {{Rating.rating}}
</div>
```

Then in the `ngOnit()`, after you've retrieved your data:

```
   // Note that this is assigning the numeric value, not the object
   console.log(this.editUserDetails.Rating.rating);
   this.selectedRating = this.editUserDetails.Rating.rating;
```

Comment: No But i stored in my database Rating=7 for one user. In my database which value is there, just i want to select that value in browser

Comment: it selects always last value. my last value is 9(radio).But user selects 7.

Comment: What is `this.editUserDetails.Rating`? Is it not the one from the database? Can you add an update to your question with the code using the technique above?

Comment: yes, user selects rating  from 5 to 10 i gave. one user selects 7. i saved in database Rating="7" like this. now i am getting that 7 to frontend and stores in editUserDetails={}. now i need to display selected radio 7 in browser

Comment: Oh ... I just realized I missed the value property on the input element. I'll update my answer.

Comment: The issue is that you are using objects and the radio button binding does see the two objects as equal. That's why it is not picking it. Check out this stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xpnepy

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this -

```
 <div class="col-md-6" *ngFor="let Rating of rates">
       <input type="radio" name="Rating" 
                          [value]="Rating" 
                         [checked]="this.editUserDetails.Rating === Rating"> 
                         <!-- above line marks your radio button checked -->
                          [value]="Rating" 
                       (change)="onSelectionChange(entry)" > 
                           {{Rating.rating}}
    </div>
```

If you really want -`onSelectionChange(entry)` is a function in your component for you to perform any action when the user changes the options -

```
onSelectionChange(entry) {
    this.selectedEntry = entry;
}
```

Comment: I already tried this, but it is not working--->[checked]="this.editUserDetails.Rating === Rating

Comment: As Deborah said, set `this.editUserDetails.Rating` in the `ngOnInit` function. Maybe the value is not assigned when the DOM was loading. It's a one-time binding. Model --> Template.

Answer (score 0):

The code is in part good, but you passing to function `radioChange` as parameter and object that contain and attribute:

```
Rating = {rating: "6"}
```

So, when you compare you use ===, and the comparation need to be an object equal, so this.editUserDetails.Rating need to be:

```
Rating = {rating: "6"}
```

If value of `this.editUserDetails.Rating` is a single number as String, you need to change the comparison to:

```
this.editUserDetails.Rating===Rating.rating
```

Comment: Not working, I tried this ----->this.editUserDetails.Rating===Rating.rating